# Will deleting a local git repo affect the remote repo?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, git-clone

I did a git clone to my computer. After that I realized that I cloned the project to wrong directory. What I want to do now is delete the project folder from my computer and do a git clone to another directory.

If I just delete the folder, will it affect the remote repository?

Any other better way to do?

Comment: See also "definition of upstream and downstream": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166. An upstream (remote) repo ignores everything of its downstream repos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the folder locally and clone it again to the directory you want to work in. Nothing will effect the remote repository. You also can just move the folder since there is no absolute path in the .git structure.

Answer (score 5):

You can just move the directory to where you actually want it. Moving it, or deleting it, will not impact the remote repository.